# Azure Devops pipeline Docker-Compose build with specific image name

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, docker-compose, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to build docker images with Docker compose task in Azure Devops pipelines and give it a specific name?

Because the names I get to the images look like `$(Build.Repository.Name)` only.

What I tried:

```
steps: 
- task: DockerCompose@0
  inputs:
    containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
    dockerRegistryEndpoint: 'Docker_Hub'
    dockerComposeFile: '**/docker-compose.yml'
    qualifyImageNames: false
    action: 'Run a Docker Compose command'
    dockerComposeCommand: 'build'
```

and without the `qualifyImageNames` too.

I tried this also but I got an image name of `xxx_{some name from the docker-compose.yaml}`:

```
- task: DockerCompose@0
  inputs:
    containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
    dockerRegistryEndpoint: 'Docker_Hub'
    dockerComposeFile: '**/docker-compose.yml'
    projectName: 'xxx'
    action: 'Build services'
    includeLatestTag: true
```

but I want to name the image something like `myreponame/somename:latest`.

I have 2 images the docker-compose need to build.

Comment: Anyone have a solution? i also have this same issue